# How do I use the OpenDNS servers for wlan0 in Aptosid?

Tags: debian, dns

How do I use the OpenDNS servers for wireless networks in Aptosid? All the methods I've found are either specific to other distros, specific to eth0 or they just don't work with Aptosid or wpa_gui.

Comment: None of this helped? http://aptosid.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=236&start=0 What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Mat I think the problem is I want to make opendns the default for wireless networks(i changed the question so it's more specific)

Comment: That link I posted includes configuration for wlan0.

Comment: @Mat I tried configuring it that way but the nameservers reset when I restarted the networking

Answer (score 1):

Having no idea, I [googled up the Aptosid manual which looks helpful](http://manual.aptosid.com) - [it refers to some text UI for network device configuration called `ceni`](http://manual.aptosid.com/en/inet-ceni-en.htm#netcardconfig):

[image: Network settings in ceni]

Have you tried this, i.e., the OpenDNS IPs in "DNS Nameservers"?

Comment: I probably should have been more specific, I want to set the opendns servers as default for wlan0 (there is no eth0) and I'm using wpa_gui to connect to networks(I'll added that to the question)

Comment: Not sure how using `wpa_gui` plays in, but the `ceni` tool allows editing network settings for `wlan0`, too, as can be recognized from [the link](http://manual.aptosid.com/en/inet-ceni-en.htm#netcardconfig).

Comment: if I use `ceni` to set the dns then I can't use `wpa_gui` to change networks(which I'm hoping to avoid because `wpa_gui` is easier to use)